# dynamically added row does not delete

Tags: jquery

I have tried various options for deleting dynamically added rows, like `.on` and `.live`, but still haven't been able to delete the newly added rows.

And I came across this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7594S/26/)

Partial JS code:

```
$(".deleterow").on("click", function(){
    var $killrow = $(this).parent('tr');
    $killrow.addClass("danger");
    $killrow.fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

but it also has the same issue.

Can someone please point out what am I missing in this JSFiddle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the click event handler to the dynamically created rows. Try this:

```
$(".container").on('click','.deleterow', function(){
var $killrow = $(this).parent('tr');
    $killrow.addClass("danger");
$killrow.fadeOut(2000, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/7594S/35/)**

Comment: @Pshah: $(".table").on("click", ".deleterow", function ()......}); will work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/7594S/36/

Comment: Thank you for pointing out @Unknown, not sure where I went wrong then. Maybe minor syntax gliche somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you.

```
$(document).on("click", ".deleterow", function () {
    var $killrow = $(this).parent('tr');
    $killrow.addClass("danger");
    $killrow.fadeOut(2000, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7594S/34/

***EDIT***

> A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one
>   element, and the event only needs to bubble up one level

in your case, `deleterow` is dynamically added content and event wont attached to that. but if you attached to the parent container element or `document` element, it will fire to new element as well

Comment: Perhaps explain why so the OP knows for future reference?

Comment: Thank you that works! I was trying $(".table").on("click", ".deleterow", function ()......}); without any luck but am still wondering why table wouldn't work since it is a parent element.But I guess if you are binding a class then may be you need a document or container as the parent element?